# Simulate PostgreSQL query timeout

Tags: database, timeout, postgresql

I would like to test the behaviour of a program which executes queries to a PostgreSQL server in case of a query timeout.

How could I simulate that?

Comment: When you say "query timeout" do you mean a `statement_timeout`? Or do you mean a TCP/IP timeout due to connection loss? Quite different behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

If you are just trying to simulate a timeout on your *application* side you could just use a dummy query like:

```
SELECT pg_sleep(seconds);
```

Where `seconds` is some integer value that would simulate a query just not coming back in a reasonable timeframe.

If you want to never come back from a query just run the above and kill the database.

```
pgrep posgres | xargs kill -15 $1
```

This would also simulate a query timeout I believe.

Answer (score 1):

How are you simulating the successful queries?  You should be able to use the same mechanism, but return `PGRES_FATAL_ERROR` (and appropriate message strings) in your `PGresult` return value .